# PHP Fatal error: Max execution time exceeded - EVEN after set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, runtime-error

I keep running into the following PHP error when running my script

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3\functions.php on line 22**

I already put this in my PHP file, and I *STILL* get this error message.

```
@set_time_limit(0);
```

Am I missing something?

`Edit`: This error only shows up after SEVERAL minutes, not after 30 seconds. Could something also be delaying its appearance?

[image]

Comment: Never **EVER** use `@` when debugging, especially when things are obviously not working. You're doing the equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Should I remove "@"? Is that only for debugging?

Comment: `@` is the error suppression operator. If set_time_limit has been disabled, you'd have gotten a warning that it was. But you've suppressed that warning with `@`, so yes... "lalalala couldn't hear you tell me it wasn't working because I didn't want to listen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) has no effect when running in safe_mode:

> This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

You can check the value of `safe_mode` and `max_execution_time` with `phpinfo()`.

---

Given the facts that you are using Windows and experiencing the timeout later than 30s you might have somewhere else in your code a reset of the timeout (`set_time_limit(30)`):

> The set_time_limit() function [..] only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. **This is not true on Windows** where the measured time is real.

Search your code for:

- `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30)`
- `set_time_limit(30)`

Comment: You should ask that (if not already answered) in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the PHP file to change the php.ini settings, you should do it yourself. Find where the php.ini is kept for WAMP, and change/add this line:

```
max_execution_time = 500;
```

Comment: I already have it modified in php.ini (max_execution_time = 10000)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PHP` config that unallows the script to change the `time_limit`.

You can change your `PHP` behavior on `php.ini` file